# Multithreaded Quicksort not sorting correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, quicksort

As a school assignment, I'm supposed to do a multithreaded quicksort algorithm using at least 2 threads, but I am having some problems with my code that I can't seem to fix.

EDIT: This is how the it looks when it's not multithreaded. I have confirmed that this works.

```
public class Sorter
{
    private int[] mInts;

    public void QuickSort()
    {
        QuickSort(mInts, 0, mInts.Length - 1);
    }

    public Sorter(int[] ints)
    {
        mInts = ints;
    }

    private int Partition(int[] ints, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivotIndex = (right + left) / 2;
        int pivotValue = ints[pivotIndex];

        Swap(ints, right, pivotIndex);

        int storeIndex = left;

        for (int i = left; i <= right - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ints[i] < pivotValue)
            {
                Swap(ints, storeIndex, i);
                storeIndex++;
            }
        }

        Swap(ints, storeIndex, right);

        return storeIndex;
    }

    private void Swap(int[] ints, int x, int y)
    {
        int temp = ints[x];
        ints[x] = ints[y];
        ints[y] = temp;
    }

    private void QuickSort(int[] ints, int left, int right)
    {
        if (left < right)
        {
            int newIndex = Partition(ints, left, right);


             QuickSort(ints, left, newIndex - 1);
             QuickSort(ints, newIndex + 1, right);
        }
    }
```

The above works fine, the code below doesn't. Right now it doesn't sort properly, and it seems to me like the bolded piece of code must be located somewhere else... or something? I'm having a very hard time understanding threaded programming, so I was hoping someone could give me some pointers on how to fix this, without having to restructure my entire program if possible. Below is how far I've gotten with the threaded version.

```
public class Sorter
{
    private int[] mInts;

    Thread myThread = null;
    int numThreads = 0;
    int maxThreads = 10;

    public void QuickSort()
    {
        QuickSort(mInts, 0, mInts.Length - 1);
    }

    public Sorter(int[] ints)
    {
        mInts = ints;
    }

    private int Partition(int[] ints, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivotIndex = (right + left) / 2;
        int pivotValue = ints[pivotIndex];

        Swap(ints, right, pivotIndex);

        int storeIndex = left;

        for (int i = left; i <= right - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ints[i] < pivotValue)
            {
                Swap(ints, storeIndex, i);
                storeIndex++;
            }
        }

        Swap(ints, storeIndex, right);

        return storeIndex;
    }

    private void Swap(int[] ints, int x, int y)
    {
        int temp = ints[x];
        ints[x] = ints[y];
        ints[y] = temp;
    }

    private void QuickSort(int[] ints, int left, int right)
    {
        if (left < right)
        {
            int newIndex = Partition(ints, left, right);

            if (numThreads < maxThreads)
            {
                numThreads++;
                myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startSort));
                myThread.Start(new SortParameters(this, ints, left, newIndex - 1));
                **QuickSort(ints, newIndex + 1, right);**
            }
        }
    }

    static void startSort(Object obj)
    {
        SortParameters sortParams = (SortParameters)obj;
        sortParams.instance.QuickSort(sortParams.ints, sortParams.left, sortParams.right);
    }

    public class SortParameters
    {
        public Sorter instance;
        public int[] ints;
        public int left;
        public int right;

        public SortParameters(Sorter instance, int[] ints, int left, int right)
        {
            this.instance = instance;
            this.ints = ints;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add the programming language to tags.

Comment: what language is this in? Java?  Also, can you supply the implementation of ParameterizedThreadStart? If this is Java, the start method should be lowercase, and doesn't take any parameters.  If not Java, I would start with a non-threaded sort and verify that your algorithm works correctly - after you know that it does you can improve it by adding multi threading

Comment: The language is C# and I've posted the code of the working non-threaded version. ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj); is a .NET method that "represents a method that executes on a System.Threading.Thread".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself the following:

1. How many threads will run for a sequence of `n` elements?
2. Is that number somehow limited by your code?
3. What will happen when that limit will be reached?

*I provide below my solution, but you might want to think about it on your own first.*

Here are my answers:

1. Theorically, your code will compute log<sub>2</sub>(n) quicksorts, since it divide each sorting between 2 subcalls after its partitioning. In your threaded version, you start one supplementary thread for each subcall, so in total you could get as many threads launched.
2. The code you provide actually limit the number of launched threads with the `maxThreads` value. So in fact, if log<sub>2</sub>(`n`) > `maxThreads`, ie. if `n` > 2<sup>`maxThreads`</sup>, the code will reach the maximum number of possible concurrent threads.
3. In the threaded code, around the highlighted part, the test on that maximum conditions the execution of any recursive calls. So if `n` is above the limit mentioned in point #2, the code will stop working correctly.

The fix is easy enough, add an `else` clause to finish the sorting up with the current thread.

```
        if (numThreads < maxThreads)
        {
            numThreads++;
            myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startSort));
            myThread.Start(new SortParameters(this, ints, left, newIndex - 1));
        }
        else {
            QuickSort(ints,left,newIndex - 1);
        }
        QuickSort(ints, newIndex + 1, right);
```

As you can see, I also moved out of the test the part that will be run by the current thread anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works perfectly =) And it is so much simpler than I thought it in my head, thanks for the explanation as well!